# Why does my MBP Retina Mid 2012 show Intel HD 4000 when it came with an Nvidia GT 650M?

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, display, gpu

When I click the Apple logo in the top left -> About This Mac -> more info... I see:

> Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB

But I bought it with nVidia GT 650m graphics. So I click the Displays tab and again it shows Intel HD Graphics 4000. So I then go back to the Overview tab and click System Report... -> Graphics/Displays. Intel HD Graphics 4000 is highlighted, but below it I **finally** see the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M!

Is my system using Intel HD Graphics 4000 instead of the more powerful GT 650M graphics? The machine has been amazing, but Unreal Engine 4 is a bit slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have set "Automatic Graphics Switching" in 
`System Preferences > Energy Saver`
discreet graphics get automatically switched on when you need it.
([via](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4110?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US))

If you are interested there are applications that let you easily force the switch such as [gfxCardStatus](http://www.heise.de/download/gfxcardstatus-1174053.htmlhttp://www.heise.de/download/gfxcardstatus-1174053.html)